# Inserting number into table C# EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

i have problem with inserting object Numbers into DbSet in C# EntityFramework CodeFirst. Db looks like this:

```
public class NumbersDatabase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Numbers> NumbersTable { get; set; }
}

public class Numbers
{
    [Key]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

[http://prntscr.com/fco3fk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/005Vo.png)

and when i try to insert missing number "4"

```
        using (var db = new NumbersDatabase())
        {
            var numbersTable = db.NumbersTable;

            var source = numbersTable.Select(number => number.Number).ToList();

            var compare = Enumerable.Range(a, b);

           // FindMissingNumbers(source, compare).ToList().ForEach(n => db.NumbersTable.Add(new Numbers() { Number = n }));

            db.NumbersTable.Add(new Numbers() { Number = 4 });

            db.SaveChanges();
            foreach (var item in source)
                Console.WriteLine(item);

        }
```

it only adding next number to collection, but "4" is still missing
[http://prntscr.com/fco3tv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRCX5.png). Why ? and how to fix that ? Thanks

Comment: The nuber is a Key property so it uses sql autoincrament use an Id field and a number field so you can add anything you want

Comment: Oh, im stupid, really thanks :)

Comment: you are using 'source' as your local data ie var source
try refreshing your source.